# How to use express-mysql-session in Typescript projects?

Tags: mysql, express, typescript, express-session

I'm trying to use express-session and express-mysql-session within a Typescript project. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as expressSession from "express-session";
import * as expressMySqlSession from "express-mysql-session";

this.express = express();
const sessionStore = new expressMySqlSession(sessionStoreConfig, this.dbConnection);
const sessionHandler = expressSession({
                ...,
                store: sessionStore
            });
this.express.use(sessionHandler);
```

It does not compile because the `store` option is of type `expressSession.Store | expressSession.MemoryStore | undefined` while `sessionStore` is of type `MySQLStore`.
What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: Notice how `session` is passed to the result of `require('express-mysql-session')` [in the example code](https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session#how-to-use), which is a step that you seem to be missing.

Comment: Hmm, yes, you are right, but how would this call look like in ES6 syntax? The following lines should be equivalent, right?
    `import * as expressSession from "express-session";`
    `import expressSession = require("express-session");`
The first one is the newer, ES6 syntax. But how would I write `require("xyz")(someparameter)` in ES6 syntax?

Besides that would this really fix the type mismatch?

Comment: It's ugly, but adding:
regenerate: (req: any, fn: (err?: any) => any) => void;
    load: (sid: string, fn: (err: any, session?: any | null) => any) => void;
    createSession: (req: any, sess: Express.SessionData) => void;
    all: (callback: (err: any, obj?: { [sid: string]: any; } | null) => void) => void;
to MySQLStore declaration in index.d.ts solves it.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import * as express        from "express";
import * as expressSession from "express-session";
import expressMySqlSession from "express-mysql-session";

const MySQLStore   = expressMySqlSession(expressSession);
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(sessionStoreConfig, this.dbConnection);
...
```

Comment: This does not compile. I get the following error (translated from German) on the line `const MySQLStore`: "The value of type 'typeof MySQLStore' cannot be called. Do you want to include 'new'?"
I found a solution, but I have the feeling that it uses an old syntax:
`const expressMySqlSession = require("express-mysql-session")(expressSession);`, followed by `return new expressMySqlSession(sessionStoreConfig, this.dbConnection);`

By the way, I use Typescript 2.4.1 in case this matters.

Comment: @TimoKunze see edit, the import for `express-mysql-session` was incorrect. The code above works in "regular" JS.

Comment: Now the import of expressMySqlSession fails with "Module '.../@types/express-mysql-session/index' has no default export."

Answer (score 2):

With both `express-session`, `express-mysql-session`, and `@types/express-mysql-session` listed as dependencies:

[Current version of the types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-mysql-session/index.d.ts) (from about two years ago) tracks an older version of `express-mysql-session`, where the default export is the class. Fortunately, there's some [backwards-compatibility](https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session/blob/d95f49d0463a708473317d2f533de29088c9a787/index.js#L487-L491) in the library for this older version, so you can instantiate it directly:

```
import MySQLSessionStore from "express-mysql-session";

const store = new MySQLSessionStore({...});
```

And the library will handle [importing the `express-session` dependency](https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session/blob/d95f49d0463a708473317d2f533de29088c9a787/index.js#L17-L20) for you.

Code never lies!

Comment: Forgetting to add `@types/express-mysql-session` fixed an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as session from 'express-session';
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

import pool from './database';
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore({
  schema: {
    tableName: 'mire_sessions',
    columnNames: {
      session_id: 'session_id',
      expires: 'expires',
      data: 'data'
    }
  }
}, pool);

const app = express();
app.use(session({
  secret: 'z',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: sessionStore
}))
```

This code worked for me. But I don't know why